# Does the Mind Spike spell end if the target foes out of range?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Mind Spike says

> On a failed save, you also always know the target’s location until the spell ends, but only while the two of you are on the same plane of existence.

DnD Beyond lists this having a range/area of 60ft.

Does this mean if my target teleports (remaining on this plane of existence) away I stop knowing where they are outside of the 60ft? Or is that the initial range?

Comment: Derp. I knew I had seen this before. I should have looked for the other question *before* answering. I almost replicated Dale's answer here lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It doesn't

Player's Handbook p.203

> Once a spell is cast, its effects aren’t limited by its range, unless the spell’s description says otherwise.

To clarify, the "Range: X" listed in spells refers to what I understand you called "initial range". The full description of its meaning can be found in the Spellcasting Chapter (Chapter 10 of PHB), under the Range section (pages 202 and 203 in the PHB), or [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Range) in the D&D Beyond page. As specified in the above quote, the spell range only affects its *casting*. Once it is cast, that entry is essentially meaningless, unless stated otherwise in the description.

In this case, the only condition for the spell to keep working is that the target remains in the same plane of existence.